# AngularJS dynamic directive loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using AngularJS and am currently loading includes based on a variable like:

```
<div ng-include="'app/views/' + field.fieldType + '.tpl.html'"></div>
```

would it be possible to load directives similarly ( key off a variable name in the template )?  Something like:

```
<div my-directive-{{field.fieldType}} />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your directive restricted to an attribute? Have you tried class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do it a little something like this.

```
.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
      var directiveName = attrs['my-directive'];
      var directive = angular.element(document.createElement(directiveName));
      var el = $compile( directive )( scope );

      angular.element(document.body).append(directive);

    }
  }
});
```

With info from [Insert directive programmatically angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656735/insert-directive-programatically-angular)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I would recommend the following instead (as the Angular way):

```
<div my-directive field-type="field.fieldType" />
```

The dangers with re-compiling a directive to achieve the same thing are not worth the risk/effort IMO.