# $broadcast appending dynamic data (rows) at wrong place using ng-scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, scrollbar, ngtable

I have used ng-scrollbar like this :

```
<tbody ng-scrollbar  rebuild-on="rebuild:me" class="scrollme" id ="tempID">
```

and in ng table , included the broadcast

getData: function($defer, params) {

```
        $scope.$broadcast('rebuild:me');
```

Now the ng-repeat is populating the tr in thead after first th instead of appending/loading it correctly in tbody

how to correctly display my results?

Comment: I guess scroll bar wont work on a table, but a div

Comment: no it works on table as well.I have tried using both static as well as dynamic data...  the problem is with the $broadcast which is not reloading the dynamic data and delegating in the correct order as it should be.

Comment: anyone there .. angularJs guys ... !!!

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
      $defer.promise.then(function(){
        $scope.$broadcast('rebuild:me');
};
...
```

right after updating table

### Edit 1

`tbody` is replacing by `div` and thus how layout became messy,check [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8VFlqs0p40HH75wQiYGV?p=preview)

### Edit 2

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxwvBUpNIo3uFnt7hm6o?p=preview) some workaround about this,need some editing,i will update later

---

### Edit 3(final)

Finally get working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlAw2xd6qSTmnyMwreZf) of [ngtable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) and [ngscrollbar](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar) together,but its not most beautiful solution but still:

#### 1.

you need separate `thead` from rest of table into new table which locate right above main table

```
<thead>
    <tr >
    <th  class="sortable" ng-class="{
                    'nameasc':'sort-asc' ,
                    'namedesc':'sort-desc'
                    }[sortTableParam]"
                    ng-click="SortBy('name')">
                    <div>name</div>
                </th>
                <th class="text-center sortable" ng-class="{
                    'ageasc':'sort-asc' ,
                    'agedesc':'sort-desc' 
                   }[sortTableParam]"
                    ng-click="SortBy('age')">
                    <div>Age</div>
                </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

#### 2.

second - hide `thead` in main table and wrap table into `div` tag,which will be processing by directive:

```
<div style="height:300px"  ng-scrollbar  rebuild-on="rebuild:me"  class="scrollme">
      <table  ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
      <thead><tr><th ></th><th ></th></tr></thead>
        <tbody >
          <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }" sortable="name">
                    {{user.name}}

                </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="age">
                    {{user.age}}
                </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

#### 3.

Clicks from header will trigger reloading data with sorting option,by binding `SortBy` function

```
 var sorting = $scope.tableParams.$params.sorting;
          var dir = sorting != null ? (sorting[param.toString()] == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'asc';
          var sort={};
          sort[param.toString()]=dir;

          $scope.tableParams.sorting(sort);
          //edit classes in header for rows imaging(check plunk)
          updatesorting(param);
        };
```

Comment: let me set up plunk a lit bit later to find out  what's going on

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8VFlqs0p40HH75wQiYGV?p=preview  i don't now how make it right except somehow recompile directive ,like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19129131/4104866 ,`tbody` is substituted by `div` and thus all layout become mess

Comment: if you dont want to dig in directive you better use another table directive like http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ which default template for table  based on `div`s

Comment: is it a bug that can be raised ... enforced div inside a table

Comment: you mean that must be checking of what target element,when applying directive?

Comment: yes , because scroll can be for table and list as well