# Dynamically add directives without templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following is how you can dynamically add an `ng-click` directive. Lets say I want to do the same thing, but I don't want to use a template. I want to add ng-click to the current element. How Can I do that?

```
.directive( 'test', function ( $compile ) {   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { text: '@' },
    template: '<p ng-click="add()">{{text}}</p>',
    replace:true,
    controller: function ( $scope, $element ) {
      $scope.add = function () {
        var el = $compile( "<test text='n'></test>" )( $scope );
        $element.parent().append( el );
      };
    }   }; });
```

This is essentially the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directives-on-angularjs), but I want to accomplish without using a template

Comment: Just making sure I'm understanding this correctly. You have element `<div test>Hello</div>` and you want it to become `<div ng-click="add()">Hello</div>` ? Or do you also want to pass the specific function to bind?

Comment: @tasseKATT your first example is essentially right. I want to write `<div add></div>` in my html, then I want it to become `<div add ng-click="add()"></div>` after angular has done its thing. The main reason I don't want to use a template is to preserve any random attributes that might be on the same element.


ps I don't really care if the html shows up like that, but basically I want my `add` directive to 'inherit' the `ng-click` directive

Comment: I can show you how in a while, but why don't you just use `ng-click`? Just trying to understand the use case.