# Dynamically adding/creating object to array from angular view to controller using two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have one controller, controller's template/view as below,

**myController**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myObject = {};
}]);
```

**myView**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-controller="myController">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.firstname" id="firstname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname" class="control-label col-xs-2">LastName</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.lastname" id="lastname">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

here whenever user enters any data it gets reflected to `myObject` with `firstname` and `lastname` as dynamic properties for `myObject`.
Now my new requirement is to add multiple dynamic views for `firstname` and `lastname` in the same view(For that I will be creating a directive and appending dynamically), and now I want `myObject` to be an `array of objects` like

```
myObjectArray = [{firsname: "abc", lastname: "xyz"},{firsname: "abc", lastname: "xyz"},{firsname: "abc", lastname: "xyz"},{firsname: "abc", lastname: "xyz"}]
```

and here each object should be populated through dynamically added views by user input using angular two way binding. But I am not sure how can I achieve this with angular, how to add object to array whenever there is a new directive template added to view dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directives-on-angularjs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Angular you should avoid thinking in terms of dynamic controls.

Here is the approach

1. You want to list firstname, lastname objects
2. You want to add a new object to this list.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.itemsToAdd = [{
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  }];

  $scope.add = function(itemToAdd) {

    var index = $scope.itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd);

    $scope.itemsToAdd.splice(index, 1);

    $scope.items.push(angular.copy(itemToAdd))
  }

  $scope.addNew = function() {

    $scope.itemsToAdd.push({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd">
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.firstName" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.lastName" />
    <button ng-click="add(itemToAdd)">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="addNew()">Add new</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice these are simply talking about model. Here is a plunk

Comment: If I have to add/append this(Firstname/Lastname) view and push its values to object how we can do that?
consider Firstname and lastname is a directive and on click of particular button I have to append more and more views and push its values to array..

Comment: I want to do something like this,
http://jsbin.com/jeqixezuzi/1/edit?html,js,output
but its not working after adding dynamic directives

Comment: @santoshkore - I've edited my answer. Again - You should let angular bindings drive the controls rather than control them manually. This edit should solve your problem

Comment: What does the ng-repeat of item in items do in this example?