# Angular JS - Load a template html from directive on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load a HTML template when a link is clicked. I have made a directive that contains `templateUrl` which loads a HTML file. I am calling a function when a link is clicked that appends a div with our custom directive "myCustomer" to a div already in index.html. whatever i have done so far is shown below, but it doesn't work.

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <a href="#" ng-click="showdiv()">show</a>
  <div id="d"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.showdiv = function(){
      $("#d").append("<div my-Customer></div>");
    };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

my-customer.html

```
<p>DIV CONTENT</p>
```

Here is the link i was testing this code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BotAQh13RVKBsOqHF1q1?p=preview)

Comment: use `$compile` service

Comment: does `myCustomer` directive meant for loading `templateUrl`?

Comment: yes, it is meant to load the url when the link is clicked

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because the angular doesn't bind the directives if you append content like this,

you need to [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service to do this and this will bind the directives against your `$scope`

so controller like,

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile)     {

    $scope.showdiv = function(){
      var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div my-Customer></div>")($scope);
      $("#d").append(compiledeHTML);
    };

}])
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WvTSifg9XhcKI6DZCfoz?p=preview)

---

**OR** good to do like this,

use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to create or removing element from html,

try this code

**Controller**,

```
....
$scope.anableCustomerDirective = false;
$scope.showdiv = function(){
  $scope.anableCustomerDirective = true;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <a href="#" ng-click="showdiv()">show</a>
      <div id="d">
          <div my-Customer ng-if='anableCustomerDirective'></div>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

---

**Suggestion**

if your main intention is to place a html content after the click, then you can use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) here and it will much cleaner and no need of a another directive.

```
<div id="d">        
    <div ng-include="templateURL"></div>
 </div>

 $scope.showdiv = function(){
      $scope.templateURL = 'my-customer.html';
 };
```

find the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyqOfWUgswBeokM3Wbin?p=preview)

Comment: Its like I asked and you made the changes in your code..Cool answer..Which is explaining all the possibility with what is wrong and which is right :p +1 from me dude. Cheers :)

Comment: This is working very nice, but what if I created a form dynamically and want to bind values with different variables?? How to get the index to dynamically added form?

Answer (score 8):

Seems like directive is only meant to load `template` from it.I'd suggest you to  use `ng-include` directive then

**Markup**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showDiv=true">show</a>
<div id="d"></div>
<div ng-include="showDiv ? 'my-customer.html': ''">
```

Comment: and also i am one of the two people who upvoted your answer...thnks :D

Comment: @VikramSinghJadon That's why I asked you in comment..Glad to help you..Thanks for appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to use `$compile`. More info: [Dynamically add directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directives-on-angularjs)

Then your controller may look like this:

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.showdiv = function(){
        var el = $compile( "<div my-customer></div>" )( $scope );
        $('#d').append( el );
    };
  }]);
```

Note that the directive invokation should look like this: `<div my-customer>`, not `<div my-Customer></div>` as you have in your code.

Comment: @pankajparkar Thanks for the tip, but I have just answered the question what was wrong in Vikram code.

Comment: you should have answer in correct way of doing it..not to get OP going in wrong way..that can lead him to may got in different issue ..Though I didn't downvoted :p

Answer (score 0):

when you do it manually with append you actually do not run $apply or $digest so the directive is not run,
can you try to do it with ng-show or ng-if ... e.g

```
  <body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <a href="#" ng-click="showdiv = true">show</a>
   <div my-customer ng-if="showdiv"></div>
  <div id="d"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

this way angular runs the $apply and the directive will be rendered.