# angular-charts.js - Line/Bar chart on click popover template

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart, chart.js

I am looking for a better way to implement a line/bar chart on `click` popup to display a list of items based on the label (x-axis) that was clicked on.

My current implementation in my apps controller is like so:

```
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    //console.log(points, evt);

    // length of points array is determined by how many series you have
    if (points.length > 0) {
        // call service to get some data based on label that was clicked on
        GetKVP.get({
            groupId: $scope.GroupId,
            type: $scope.Grouping,
            label: points[0].label, // label is the same no matter how many points you have
        }).$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    if (data.kvps.length > 0) {
                        var html = "<div class='temp popover' style='display: block; position: absolute; top: " + evt.pageY + "px; left: " + evt.pageX + "px;'><div class='popover-inner'><h3 class='popover-title'>KVPs</h3><div class='popover-content'>";
                            angular.forEach(data.kvps, function (val, key) {
                                html += "<a class='' data-ng-click='OpenKVP(" + val.Id + ")'>" + val.Name + "</a><br>";
                            });
                            html += "</div></div></div>";
                            $("div.app-container").append(html);
                        } else {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    // report that error has occured
                });
    }

    // remove popover after 30 seconds
    //todo: this needs a better implementation as it doesn't take into account how long it takes to fetch the data
    $timeout(function () {
        $("div.temp").remove();
    }, 30000); // deafult delay is 0 milliseconds
};
```

To summarise when a user clicks on the chart my app fetches a list of items corresponding to the label and displays it in a popup.

My issue is that when I click on the item in that popup `ngClick` binding doesn't trigger. Leading me to believe that I am incorrectly binding my popup template.

I could do something with jQuery but then why I bother using angular in the first place; right?

Alternatively, I could create a partial/inline template that will bind correctly. But with this implementation, I don't know how to instantiate multiple pop-ups with each click.

Ref:
AngularJS - [scrip](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)
[angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)
UI Bootstrap - [popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)



Update:
I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30967457/3720463) which suggested using `$compile`. By doing so angular parses the html which in turn wires up my `ngClick`.

Resulting in the following change to the code above:

```
$("div.app-container").append($compile(html)($scope));
```