# I want to refresh div tag onclick of image using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image

I am not able to refresh this piechart div on click of that image using angularjs

`div` containing my image:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder blue">
                        <div class="panel-left pull-left blue">
                            <i class="fa fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-right">
                            <h3>Assessment</h3>
                        </div>
                        <img src="assets/images/refresh.png" ng-click="refreshChart()"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

div i want to refresh:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                          **<div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-blue" data-percent="82"><span class="percent">82%</span>**
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

app.js code

```
var sampleApp1 = angular.module('sampleApp1', []);
sampleApp1.controller('dashctrl', function($scope) {

$scope.refreshChart = function (){
$('.chart').data('#easypiechart-blue').update(40);
};
```

});

Comment: try this ans, it will solve your problem
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30967457/7808007)

Comment: The easiest option would be to use ng-if to toggle the two parts on click.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method on your controller (AngularJs) and use this to redraw(reset the data and update chart) `$('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(40);` .

```
$scope.refreshChart = function (){
    $('.chart').data('newChartData').update(40);
}
```

and in your html

```
<img src="assets/images/refresh.png" data-ng-click="refreshChart()"/>
```

The best option is to do a little detection work on yourself and see that your case is exactly what they have on first page. button to refresh pie charts (https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/)