# Use angularjs directive attribute in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know I shouldn't be using jQuery in combination with Angular, but this is just for the demonstration purposes.

I'm struggling with understanding as to how to inject/insert a directive's attribute inside the controller?

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $('#myDiv1').html('<p>This works</p>');

  //this below doesn't work when injecting directive attribute
  $('#myDiv2').html('<p my-directive></p>');

})
.directive("myDirective", [function () {
        return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          var controllerOptions, options;
          element.text('Hello There');
        }
      };
}]);
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/sBM7nJhCbFOIAEg4zfoO?p=preview)

Can anyone help please? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe it's for demo purposes and you are trying to achieve something greater, but why not just have the directive already in your view? If its a directive that needs to be shown/hidden at certain times, you can use ng-show or ng-if

Comment: in any case, this solution looks like what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279343/736967

Comment: Its working , the plunker your provided , http://plnkr.co/edit/eA3a4FttXd5ahmTVV5le?p=preview isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to following

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {

  $('#myDiv1').html('<p>This works</p>');

  //this below doesn't work when injecting directive attribute
  $('#myDiv2').html('<p my-directive></p>');
$compile($("#myDiv2"))($scope);

})
.directive("myDirective", [function () {
        return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          var controllerOptions, options;
          element.text('Hello There');
        }
      };
}]);
```