# 3rd party directive inside another directive while using "controller as ... " syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, lumx

This is code snippet that recreates my problem:

html:

```
...
<div ng-controller="worker as workerCtrl">
    <my-directive label="label" controllerAs="workerCtrl" function="fileUpload(e, this.options)"></my-directive> 
</div>
```

controller:

```
...
function fileUpload(file, options){...}
...
```

directive:

```
function myDirective($compile) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var htmlText = '<lx-file-input ' +
            'change="'+attrs.controllerAs+'.'+attrs.uploadFunction+'" ' +
            'label="'+attrs.label+'"></lx-file-input>';
        element.replaceWith($compile(htmlText)(scope));
    }
}
```

Should be:
('lx-file-input' is a 3rd party directive...)

```
<lx-file-input change="workerCtrl.fileUpload(e, this.options)" label="someLabel"</lx-file-input>
```

The problem is that the timing of Angular compiling and linking is off, and the templates is left with HTML string instead of the compiled function.
I know it will work if i will set the controller inside the directive but I want it to use the same function in the same 'workerCtrl' scope from the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

First you can try to pass the function from the outside like the `on-close` in the official [Angular guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  {{message}}
  <my-dialog ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog(message)">
    Check out the contents, {{name}}!
  </my-dialog>
</div>
```

But I don't see why you should not create a bridge function in the scope of your directive that calls on to the desired function. I'd prefer this way.

Recently I had almost the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directives-on-angularjs/31413530#31413530) as you have just posted. You may find other useful posts there too.

Comment: //HackMagicDragonsBeHere What about a horrible 2-step instantiation? Creating a temporary directive that parses the controller function and replaces itself with a directive that actually brings in the 3rd party directive. :D Just wondering whether it would work...

Answer (score 1):

I have posted my solution here: https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-lumx/issues/12#issuecomment-126464833