# how to add dynamically ng-click in datatable using angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to add dynamically an anchor tag link in datatable, tag is added but ng-click event not working.

my angularjs code:

```
listApp.controller('mylistctr', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$compile', function ($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
 $timeout(function () {
    if (!$.fn.dataTable) return;

    dtInstance1 = $('#datatable1').dataTable({
        'paging': true,  // Table pagination
        'ordering': true,  // Column ordering 
        'info': true,  // Bottom left status text
        sAjaxSource: '/AutomationFX/api/clusters/phones/phonelist',
        aoColumns: [
          { mData: 'column1' },
          { mData: 'column2' },
          { mData: 'column3' },
          { mData: 'column4' },
          { mData: 'column5' }
        ], "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "aTargets": [4],
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<a ng-click="openWindow('+data+')"><img src="app/img/a.png"/></a>';

            }
        }]
    });

});
});
```

My html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="datatable1" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr></tr>
                    <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
                    <th style="width:15%">LastName</th>
                    <th style="width:15%">Contact</th>
                    <th style="width:45%">Desc</th>
                    <th style="width:10%">Action</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

so far I have found that I have to compile dynamic html, but i have not found right solution yet.

Comment: You can use $compile service wrapping it into a directive, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directives-on-angularjs

Comment: not duplicate, i have already checked that i am looking to compile element in datatable inside

Comment: Try `return $compile( '<a ng-click="openWindow('+data+')"><img src="app/img/a.png"/></a>')($scope);`

Comment: @AmitArya you must have missed something while doing compiling element

Comment: @AmitArya Try `return $compile('a>...</a>')($scope)[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: i think by this way i will get <img src="app/img/a.png"/> only not full anchor tag with ng-click event

Comment: thanks, hope so ng-click will work

Comment: ng-click not working yet