# How to use angular-translate and ng-xeditable's validation together?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) and [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/). I have the following field:

```
<a href="#"
       editable-text="name"
       onbeforesave="validate($data)"
       onaftersave="save(name)">
       {{ name }}
</a>
```

In the **validate** function I'm validating the **name** field and if everything is correct I'm saving the data through the save method. However, if the **name** field is not correct, I should return a validation message. There's an [example](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#validate-local) in the documentation of angular-xeditable of such a scenario.

```
$scope.validate = function(name) {
    if (name.length > 10) {
        return "Validation Message that doesn't need multiple languages";
    }
}
```

Now, if the **name** field is more than 10 characters long, a message will be display to the user and the data won't be saved. However, I'm using angular-translate in my app and I want to show a message that is translated in the appropriate language. Moreover, I want to customize my messages for different scenarios so that I won't need to have thousands of different messages for all of my fields.

For example:

```
var translationsEN = {
    STRING_LENGTH_MESSAGE: '{{ fieldName }} should be between {{ min }} and {{ max }}',
    REQUIRED: '{{ fieldName }} is required.'
}
var translationsDE = {
    // The same messages in German.
}
```

Now the best thing that I could think of is changing the code in the validate function to this:

```
$scope.validate = function(name) {
    if (name.length > 10) {
        $translate('VALIDATION_MESSAGE', { fieldName: 'name', min: 0, max: 10 })
            .then(function(translation) {
                $scope.message = translation;
            }
        );

        return $scope.message;
    }
}
```

Of course, at the time of showing the error message, the error message is not translated yet and the message that is shown to the user is not correct.

How can I achieve the desired result - to show translated validation messages to the user?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2fsw/56/) of my example.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a fair amount of hours with this today :)

What seems to be a workaround is compiling an element that'll have the `translate` directive, so the OP's function would look sth like:

```
$scope.validateName = function(name) {
    if (name.length > 10) {
      console.log('fail')
      var element = $compile('<span translate="VALIDATION_MESSAGE"></span>')($scope)[0];
      return $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply();
        return element.textContent
      }, 10);
    }
  };
```

A bit more on compiling and dynamically adding directives (which is what would also help solve the task — if we could dynamically set the translate directive to the error container) is in the answers to this question: [Dynamically add directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs)

UPDATE: changed the code a bit, so that it works with validating the name in controller. `$timeout` might not be needed if the validation is performed on server but in this case it wouldn't be possible to use `$scope.$apply()` otherwise without which the result wouldn't be interpolated.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsdezz/anx8gmry/1/) — first input is validated in the OP's way, the second — with the function above.

Hope it helps.