# Dynamically adding directive in controller scope Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to check, whether the below mentioned situation is possible or not.
Suppose, I have created a directive say "dummyDir", having **restrict** attribute as "EA" and **link** function just copying data from scope datasource to a variable, also, templateUrl being set to a url say "template.html".
Now, from a controller say "callController", which is having a method say "callDirective", which is creating an element of type "dummy-dir" and appending this element to the **body** element.
Now in the page, when this "callDirective" method is invoked/called, this "dummy-dir" element is present in the page, but the referencing templateUrl "template.html", is not present in the page.

So, whether I am doing some thing wrong because of which this template is not getting rendered or this is not possible from AngularJS?

Waiting for reply.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert directive dynamically? That is possible, but you need to [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the element that you have created so that it is recognized by Angular

Comment: Reproduce your problem with some simple line of code and attach the code here. It will help everyone to understand you problem easily. You can use plunker or jsfiddle.

Comment: Check this answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs, http://jsfiddle.net/Chyngz/k9htwjae/