# Angularjs - Refresh tr after attribute add for directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Based off of : [Dynamically add directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs)

I am trying to add a directive after to an element after the element's creation and page load.

$(nRow) refers to a  element. Currently with the following code nothing happens the elements doesn't get the attributes. If I remove the replaceWith I get the element with the attributes but the directive isn't applied.

```
 var row = angular.element($(nRow)).clone();
    row.attr("tooltips", "");
    row.attr("tooltip-template", "tooltip");
    row.attr("tooltip-smart", "true");
    row.attr("tooltip-speed", "slow");
    row.attr("tooltip-size", "large");
    row = $compile(row)($scope);
    $(nRow).replaceWith(row);
    $scope.$apply();
```

Comment: can you please add some more code or plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(nRow) was not referencing the right object.