# ng-model added dynamically is not working?

Tags: angularjs, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxScheduler and angular js.
I inserted an ng-model attribute within checkbox and select element of lightbox of  dhtmlxScheduler - ng-model="isallday".

```
    link:function($scope, $element, $attrs, ...) {
    ...
    angular.element(document.querySelector( '[name="isallday"]' )).attr('ng-model', 'isallday');
    angular.element( document.querySelector( ".dhx_section_time" )
    .getElementsByTagName("select") ).attr('ng-class', '{dhx_time_disable: isallday}');
```

Clicking on the checkbox doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ng-model is directive. But you are just adding an attribute to your element. It is not seen by angular. 
check this out [Dynamically add directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs)

Comment: I just found a solution.

var el = angular.element(...);

$injector = el.injector();

$injector.invoke(function($compile){

  $compile(el)($scope);
  
})

Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: ya, I was going to say you would need to run `$compile(element)($scope);`