# javascript disabled attribute not working in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written the following line to add an `disable` attribute to an element in angular

`angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("pit")).setAttribute('disabled');`

but it is not working and throwing an error:

`angular.element(...).setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: You should definitely use `ng-disabled` if you are using AngularJS.

Comment: yeah i too was thinking that but that element is dynamically created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) returns a jQuery/jQuery lite wrapped element, not the raw DOM element.

You can set it using jQuery methods:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("pit")).attr('disabled', true);
```

---

This is not really the angular way though. Consider adding a service to provide values to `ng-disabled`, or directive to manage the disabled state.

Comment: the element is dynamically created how can i use ng-disabled on it?

Comment: You can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to create dynamic elements which are still angular-able. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: i am trying to create frost screen effect whenever i click on a particular button all the contents should get blurred for that i have applied blur class on them(CSS) and I am then trying to disable thier functionalities in which case i am disabling them. so can u suggest me some other way to do so...

Comment: update your question if a jsfiddlerso we may help you.

Answer (score 2):

`angular.element` returns [a jQuery or jqLite Object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), both has an `attr`() function that you can use instead, so:

instead of:

`angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("pit")).setAttribute('disabled');`

you should write:

```
angular.element(".pit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has built in jQuery, so you could just add

```
$(".pit").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".pit")).setAttribute('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

This statement will work only if the element is an input type

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("pit")).attr('disabled', true);
```

Or use `ng-disabled` directive. this is the best way to disable an element in angular.