# JS word highlighting and categorizing tool

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highlighting, tagging

I am working on a project using AngularJs 1. I am looking for a library/tool which allows the user to click on any word of a text displayed and then allows him to categorize (tag) and highlight the word in order to its category. (Bonus: It would be nice to add categories on the go).

Does anyone know one or several JS libraries/ tools for that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you would like to have maybe you find AngularJS material as solution. 
I know it almost have a [directive for text highlighting](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdHighlightText)

And now, looking for it I have found [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/). It seems to be a tag directive as you wish.

If the reach is more specific you could try to get it by JS directly I think. 
Or doing your own directive.

What you could do in your case is add the directive when an event (onclick). Check [how to dynamically add directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs)
Or do your custom directive react to those events.

Comment: I will look into those two! But how do I make every word in a text clickable?

Comment: To do every word clickable you can use JS split() method to parse the content of a div (using space character as separator) to individualize them by code. For example doing every word to be contained in a span dynamically changing html when text is edited or when page is loaded. Or saved by any reference.