# AngularJS use Directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to use directive from controller in angular 1.6.*.

I explain better with code.

**Controller**

```
$scope.directive = [
   "<span my-directive></span>",
   "<span my-directive2></span>",
   "<span my-directive3></span>"
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div>{{directive}}</div>
```

My solution is:

**Controller**

```
directive.forEach(function (item) {
    $compile(item)($scope).appendTo('.navbar');
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

But my solution is DOM dependent, is a bad solution.
I need a smart solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: mmmm, there is a lot of solutions, and as i see this is not work. But the most important of all, is FOR WHAT IS THIS CODE?

Comment: [Most solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279244/dynamically-add-directive-in-angularjs) use `$compile` but with respect to the parent that directives are bound to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own directive which will do this binding for you similarly to `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-html`.

Please consider the following example:

**Directive**

```
function MyBindCompileDirective($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('myBindCompile', () => elem.html($compile(scope.myBindCompile)(scope).html()))
        }
    };
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myBindCompile', MyBindCompileDirective);
```

**Usage in HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in directives" my-bind-compile="item"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, is another way, but is DOM dependent too.   
and the scope is isolated, i can't.pass the data    
Example
`"<span my-directive3 myData='data'></span>"`

Comment: Instead of an isolated scope you could just use `attr.$observe`, but the example with isolated scope seemed more relatable to me. I updated the answer to use `$observe` instead of `$watch`.

Comment: Your code give me a problem, but i have understand your idea. 
And i understand that is impossible without $compile and html().
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate in a ngRepeat and put the directive directly, changing only what is needed. collection is defined in the controller

```
<div ng-repeat="model in collection">
 <span my-directive variable="model"></span>
</div>
```